# how can i get the number of bytes available to read on async socket on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, asyncsocket

I have a simple tcp/ip server written in c++ on linux. I'm using asynchronous sockets and epoll. Is it possible to find out how many bytes are available for reading, when i get the EPOLLIN event?

Comment: Why? The recv() will tell you, and give you the data too.

Comment: Well, sometimes it can be quite convenient to know the size of buffer, that should be allocated for reading. For example, in kqueue the number of bytes is returned in data field.

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't be allocating a buffer for reading. That just creates garbage, heap fragmentation, etc. You should use a locally allocated byte array.

Comment: But what should i do, if the received data should be processed in some other thread? For example, i have a server with one thread that accepts network connections, reads requests, and transfer them to another thread (or even pool of threads), that do some processing?

Comment: If you're using `epoll()` you must be using non-blocking I/O. Not the same thing as asynchronous I/O.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `man 7 tcp`:

```
int value;
error = ioctl(sock, FIONREAD, &value);
```

Or alternatively `SIOCINQ`, which is a synonym of `FIONREAD`.

Anyway, I'd recommend just to use `recv` in non-blocking mode in a loop until it returns `EWOULDBLOCK`.

**UPDATE:**

From your comments below I think that this is not the appropriate solution for your problem.

Imagine that your header is 8 bytes and you receive just 4; then your `poll/select` will return `EPOLLIN`, you will check the `FIONREAD`, see that the header is not yet complete and wait for more bytes. But these bytes never arrive, so you keep on getting `EPOLLIN` on every call to `poll/select` and you have a no-op busy-loop. That is, `poll/select` are *level-triggered*. Not that an edge triggered function solves your problem either.

At the end you are far better doing a bit of work, adding a buffer per connection, and queuing the bytes until you have enough. It is not as difficult as it seems and it works far better. For example, something like that:

```
struct ConnectionData
{
    int sck;
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
    size_t offset, pending;
};

void OnPollIn(ConnectionData *d)
{
    int res = recv(d->sck, d->buffer.data() + offset, d->pending);
    if (res < 0) 
        handle_error();
    d->offset += res;
    d->pending -= res;
    
    if (d->pending == 0)
        DoSomethingUseful(d);
}
```

And whenever you want to get a number of bytes:

```
void PrepareToRecv(ConnectionData *d, size_t size)
{
    d->buffer.resize(size);
    d->offset = 0;
    d->pending = size;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Yes, i can use recv or read like this, but i have a binary protocol, that stores the packet size in it's header, so i thought the code can become much simpler, if i would check if the header is already available for reading or not.

Comment: @PavelDavydov: Indeed, having a buffer and accumulate here may be (just) a bit complicated. But I think that you may be cutting too many corners... please, see my update.

Comment: Yes, getting EPOLLIN endlessly can be a problem, thanks. My server acts in a way similar to the one you recommend, i just thought that maybe it can be done easier and cleaner.